# SharePoint not showing links under subsites(dropdown) on top link bar of home page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, branding

I have a home page with various sub sites showing on top link bar( of home page), problem is I all the links in all sub sites are not visible(dropdown appears white) 
SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature is activated and when I go to  Site Settings > Navigation, all links are there in their correct subsites, even when I try to add a new link it doesn't appear.

Ticking show subsites and show pages does not seems to solve this problem.
This though is working on my dev server(which mirrors the current affected production servers). Any ideas how I can make this pain go away?

Comment: I realized that this only happens when i deploy my new master page, with old master page everything works fine, strangely i also deployed same master page on my Dev server/site and it works just fine. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it the static display levels (set in the master page)? [Customizing SharePoint Top Navigation Menu and Quick Launch Bar ](http://doolbox.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/customizing-sharepoint-top-navigation.html)